# How do I conditionally intercept touch events?

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, touch, swift

I'm writing a custom keyboard extension for iOS 8 in Swift, and I'm having trouble implementing a Swype-style scribble overlay. Right now, my keyboard features a base `UIView` (the `view` property of my `UIInputViewController`) that has a number of `UIButtons` corresponding to keys on the keyboard. Each of these keys responds to `touchUpInside` events, and has `UISwipeGestureRecognizers` that input secondary characters when swiped up or down. I've overridden `touchesBegan:withEvent:` to add my scribble overlay view as a subview and `touchesEnded:withEvent:` to remove my scribble overlay view in my `UIInputViewController`.

Currently, if I attempt to scribble starting from some of the spacing between buttons, the scribble overlay view appears properly. However, if I start scribbling from on top of a `UIButton`, the `UIButton` captures the touch event and doesn't forward it to my `UIInputViewController`.

How can I implement my keyboard in such a way that my scribble overlay view appears if the user scribbles between buttons, but handles button presses/swipes otherwise?

**--EDIT--**

I've attempted to resolve this by overriding the `touchesBegan/Moved/Ended/Cancelled` methods to forward the event to the next responder. If I click on a button and then click on another, I can get a scribble to appear between the two. However, I still can't get anything to draw on the button as a scribble between buttons. Anyone have a better idea?

**--EDIT #2--**

Currently, my view hierarchy is set up like this:
`UIView` (from the `UIInputViewController`)
Subviews: All of my buttons, then my `ScribbleView` overlaying the subviews.

If I set `userInteractionEnabled` to true on my `ScribbleView`, I can get scribbling to appear anywhere, regardless of the starting location, but then I lose my button functionality.

As for source code, I've been experimenting with various configurations of passing touching events and whatnot, but the main body of code can be found here: https://github.com/Kamaros/ELDeveloperKeyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, as I didn't try to work with UIInputViewControllers yet. But how about subclassing UIButton and then overriding the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:` methods in order to forward these events to your UIInputViewController?

Comment: Definitely an option, though I'm not sure how this will work in conjunction with the gesture recognizers I have attached to each button. Worth trying though, if no one thinks of anything more clever.

Comment: Since you're getting the scribble between buttons (and not on the buttons), isn't it just a matter of view hierarchy? I mean, aren't you drawing below the button itself? Again, it's just a guess since I don't have access to your code. Alternatively, if you're into kludges, you could always put an empty UIView above all buttons and draw on it, instead of drawing wherever you're drawing now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set your ScribbleView interationEnabled to YES and forward to the button below  the touchEvents you don't want. For example, if you recognize a long press in the same spot or a tap then you know the user wants to press the button.